# How does choosing an even window size actually add a cyclical component to the model?

Tags: time-series, moving-average, filter, moving-window

I am new to Time Series Analysis. Say, we have a time series $(y_{t})_{t}$ that we want to filter with a moving average filter. I have been told that we should choose the window size $L$ of the filter to be uneven. Apparently, if it were even, this would introduce another cyclical component into the data. My question is: why? Why would an even window size introduce a cyclical component, while an uneven window size would not?

There seems to be no mathematical justification for this...

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but even-ness/odd-ness can easily create cycles in pretty trivial mathematical models. For example $y_t = \alpha + -1^{i+1} \rho y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t}$, where $i$ is an integer creates cycles when $i$ is even (and $|\rho|$ is far enough from zero that you can see equilibration occuring after a perturbation), and no cycles when $i$ is odd.